# MySQL Order By Specific Starting Characters

Tags: mysql

My database includes a field that specifies a proficiency level at a certain task. It includes three options: beginner, intermediate, and expert. What I am trying to do is find a concise way to query these skills and order them by proficiency (highest first).

Sorting them simply by alphanumeric characters does not work because intermediate would come first, rather than expert.

Other than changing the field values so that the skill names are ordered alphabetically, is there any way to concisely order based on specific starting characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`case`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) operator to set a numerical value

```
SELECT CASE proficiency 
  WHEN 'beginner' THEN 1 
  WHEN 'intermediate' THEN 2 
  WHEN 'expert' THEN 3 
END as proficiencyLevel from tasks
ORDER BY proficiencyLevel;
```